# strong and weak* limits

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence, strong-convergence

I have the sequence $\Phi_n(x)=\sin(nx) \ \forall x\in(0,\pi),n\in \mathbb{N}$ and I know that it weakly* converges to $0$ in $L^{\infty}((0,\pi))$.
Now I have to show that it doesn't converge strongly in $L^{1}((0,\pi))$.
Can I say that if it should converge in $L^{1}((0,\pi))$ it must converges to the same limit of the weak* convergence? or since the space is different also the limits can be different?

Comment: What do you mea by strong convergence here? Norm convergence?

Comment: Anyway, I'm not sure what is your question. Are you asking if, in general, if a sequence $f_n\in L^\infty\cap L^1$ converges weakly* in $L^\infty$ and strongly in $L^1$, then the limit is the same?

Comment: You are treating it as a sequence  of $L^{\infty}$. Strong convergence would mean convergence in the norm of $L^{\infty}$, not $L^{1}$

Answer (score 0):

$\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} |\sin x |dx =\int_{0}^{\pi} |\sin (y+n\pi) |dy=\int_0^{\pi} |\sin y|dy$. Call this fixed positive number $A$. By Cesaro's Theorem the averages of $(\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} |\sin x |dx)$ also tend to $A$. This means $\frac 1 n \int_0^{n\pi} |\sin x |dx \to A$. By a change of variable this gives $\int_0^{\pi} |\Phi_n (x)|dx \to A$. Suppose $\Phi_n \to g$ in $L^{1}$. Then there is a subsequence  $(\Phi_{n_k})$ which converges to $g$ a.e. By DCT $\int \Phi_{n_k} f \to \int fg$ for all $f \in L^{1}$. Hence, $\Phi_{n_k} \to g$ in $weak^{*}$ topology. By uniqueness of $weak^{*}$ limits  we get $g=0$ a.e. But then $\Phi_n \to 0$ in $L^{1}$ which is  contradiction to the fact that $\int_0^{\pi} |\Phi_n (x)|dx \to A>0$.

Comment: Since I know that $\Phi_n(x)$ weakly* converges to $0$ in $L^{\infty}$, in order to prove that $\Phi_n(x)$ doesn't converge strongly in $L^1$ is correct to prove that $||\Phi_n(x)-0||_{L^1}=||\Phi_n(x)||_{L^1}$ is different from $0$?

Comment: That requires an argument. It is not immediate. I have given details of that implication using DCT.  Remember that you are treating $(\Phi_n)$ as  a sequence in $L^{\infty}$ as well as $|L^{1}$  so standard FA arguments don't work here.  @Fabio